Как сделать сцены в aiogram глобальной
Как сделать сцены в aiogram глобальной, а не привязанной к конкретному чату.
Делаю бота для игры в мафию и для того чтобы было удобнее работать решил вынести день и ночь в разные сцены, но вот беда сцена работает локально для каждого чата отдельно, а ночь она как бы для всех

Так вы устанавливайте день или ночь в боте, а не в чате. И тогда для всех статус будет един

так и устанвливаю, просто сама сцена создается для одного чата
